# How to show a 360 degree image in react native, in an expo managed workflow

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to implement a modal in which I show the user a 360 degree image and he can move the image freely, the problem is the only library I found for this, https://github.com/lightbasenl/react-native-panorama-view, can not be used in an expo managed workflow. I also found this old post [How to show 360 images in the react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595078/how-to-show-360-images-in-the-react-native/54452428), but the answer is very old and I can't seem to make it work.